# Атрибут Vue.js в сгенерированном html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, click, атрибуты

Мне нужно сделать обработчик события click для html элемента, который динамически генерируется с помощью vue.js(v-html). 
Каким образом это реализовать? Когда пишу один из атрибутов @click="названиеМетода", то после генерации этот атрибут не работает.
Есть ли рабочая альтернатива?

Comment: Ну как минимум показать проблемный код. Сам элемент на который вешаете событие и сам обработчик. На словах не совсем понятна ваша проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разметка подставленная через атрибут `v-html` не обрабатывается как шаблон (поэтому, в ней не будут работать атрибуты и директивы Vue).

И прямое назначение обработчиков DOM-элементам *внутри Vue-приложения, является костылем*.

### Vue-way решение

Динамическое создание компонента, и его отображение через `<component>`:

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app', 
  data: {
    dynamic: null
  }, 
  methods: {
    setDynContent() {
      this.dynamic = Vue.component('dyn-cmpnt', { template: `
        <div class="dyn">
          Lorem <span @click="$emit('my-evt', 'foo'); $parent.logClick($event);">ipsum</span> dolor sit amet
        </div>
      `}); 
    }, 
    logClick(e)   { console.log(e.target.outerHTML); }, 
    onMyEvt(data) { console.log('Данные события: ' + data); }
  }
});
```

```css
.dyn { margin: 1rem 0 0 0; }
.dyn > span { color: #47f; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="setDynContent">Динамический контент</button>
  <component :is="dynamic" @my-evt="onMyEvt"></component>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Vue предоставляет две возможности "сообщить" родительскому компоненту о событии в дочернем, обе возможности показаны в примере.

Несмотря на то что указание метода/свойства родителя через `$parent` выглядит короче и проще - **лучше выпускать кастомные события через `$emit`**, так как обращение через `$parent` является источником потенциальных ошибок.

К тому же, родительский экземпляр может подписываться на события выборочно... А при обращении напрямую через `$parent` - такой возможности нет: в этом случае получается что дочерний экземпляр "управляет" родительским (и это абсолютно нелогично).

*<sub>Третья, не показанная тут возможность обмена данными - через действия и мутации Vuex. В больших приложениях это наиболее удобный способ, но он за рамками вопроса.</sub>*

---

А когда разметка шаблона генерируется асинхронно - нужно использовать [асинхронную фабрику компонента](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B).

Comment: Разметку шаблона (или весь объект компонента) конечно же можно передавать аргументом метода - хардкодить вовсе не обязательно (в примере это сделано для простоты).

Answer (score 0):

Обработка событий не vue компонентов сгенерированных динамически с помощью `v-html` может производится с помощью обычного js используя ссылку `ref` на элементы! Пример ниже:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      myHtml: '<a href="#">click me</a>'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs['mydiv'].firstChild.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('clicked: ', event.target);
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-html="myHtml" ref="mydiv"></div> 
</div>
```